# How can I improve ContourPlot to get smooth curve?

Tags: plotting, graphics, smoothing

I am working on the `ContourPlot` to creat contour line of a `InterpolatingFunction` recently. This is my [data](http://www.wikiupload.com/QD930S9IBVUS9FM).
This is my simple code:

```
Get["C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\data.mx"]

hx = Derivative[1, 0][mdfun];
hxxx = Derivative[3, 0][mdfun];
scaledA[d_, B_, k_, e_, hx_, h_, hxxx_] := (3*d*(1 + B*k)*hx)/((k + h + B*k*h)^3*e) + 3*1/e*hxxx + 3*1/e*hx;
A = scaledA[-1, 1, 0.1, 0.05, hx[x, 11.35], mdfun[x, 11.35], hxxx[x, 11.35]];
scaledϕ[A_, z_, h_, B_, k_, hx_, e_, m_] := A*(z^3/6 - (h*z^2)/2) -
m ((1 +B*k)*k*hx*z^2)/((k + h + B k h)^2*e);

sl = ContourPlot[scaledϕ[A, y, mdfun[x, 11.35], 1, 0.1, hx[x, 11.35], 0.05, -5],
{x, 0, 2*Sqrt[2] π}, {y, 0, mdfun[x, 11.35]}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 <= y <= mdfun[x, 11.35]],
ImageSize -> 600, Contours -> 20, PlotPoints -> 100,
ContourShading -> None,
ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin], Frame -> False]
```

I got a graph with zigzag curve.

I have tried to increase `PlotPoints` up to 100, `MaxRecursion` up to 6 (which has turned  off my machine :) ), and `PrecisionGoal` up to 10 (which is less than the `PrecisionGoal`(40) of my `InterpolatingFunction`) that run away rather easy :P, and also `PerformanceGoal->"Quality"`. However, by anyway, I can not get an acceptable plot. Is there any way to improve the quality of `ContourPlot`? Is there any possible to use filter?

Comment: About how long does it take to generate the contour?  Even with `PlotPoints -> 100` deleted, I still am waiting for a result.

Comment: Hello, @bbgodfrey. Thank you again! In this code, I use `Contours -> 20` rather than specifying any value to my function, so it take about 50s in my common PC to generate the contour even `PlotPoints -> 100`. Please feel free to test it :).

Comment: My PC took almost 90 sec just to create the 1D plot below.  Is it possible that we have different versions of the data.mx file?  Very strange.  By the way, feel free to contact me by email, if you wish.  Brendan.Godfrey@ieee.org

Comment: The data file is fairly large and I'm on a slow connection, so forgive me for asking, but does the file contain the original data array or just the `InterpolatingFunction`? As bbgodfrey's answer shows, the oscillations are inherent in the `InterpolatingFunction`, and it's quite possible that adjusting the parameters of `Interpolation` could solve the problem, but to do that we would need the original data.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, Thank you Dr. Godfrey :). I will contact you properly! The data should be same. Please try my `ContourPlot` in the original post, I have checked OP with the data link again, it takes 51.79 seconds to generate the contour line. My machine: i5-3470 CPU@ 3.2 GHz, RAM 4G, MMA9.0.

Comment: @ Rahul. Yes, the data is a little bit large. It take about 1min to download. The data contain `InterpolatingFunction` that is `mdfun[x,t]` a function of x and t, which is obtained by solved a PDE using NDSlove. It is the original data. You can export and import the data you want, say, `origplot =Plot[mdfun[x, 11.35], {x, 0, 2*Sqrt[2] \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2*Sqrt[2] \[Pi]}, {0, 1.1}}], data = Cases[origplot, Line[data_] :> data, -4, 1][[1]]; Export["11.35.txt", data, "Table"] (change to .dat before import)`. In my contour, I just want to use `mdfun[x,t]` and its derivatives at a instant.

Comment: `hxxx` oscillates rapidly at both small and large `x`, perhaps because `mdfun` does not have quite enough accuracy there to support three derivatives.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, I think your guess is right. I am thinking how can I eliminate hxxx in my function. Is there any method to use of **Filter** `FitPolynomial[data_] := Fit[data, Table[x^n, {n, 0, 10}], x]` to smooth my data?

Comment: I suggest that the data that went into `mdfun[x, 11.35]` be incorporated into an `InterpolatingFunction` with `InterpolationOrder` greater than the default value of `3`, perhaps `5` to see what happens.  Good night for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A slice of the function

```
Plot[scaledϕ[A, .2, mdfun[x, 11.35], 1, 0.1, hx[x, 11.35], 0.05, -5], {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Slice through contour plot]

suggests that the irregular contours and long running time are due to the fine structure of `mdfun`.  Averaging over the fine structure before generating the `ContourPlot` may give smoother contours, if details of the fine structure are not needed in the plot.

**Addendum: Smoothed Contours**

The small, rapid oscillations apparent in the plot above can be traced to `hxxx`, the third derivative of `mdfun` with respect to `x`. This oscillation can be eliminated, and the computational speed improved as well, by creating 1-D interpolation functions and then applying `LowpassFilter` to `hxxx`:

```
im = 199;
mddta1d = Table[x = i N[2*Sqrt[2] π]/im; {x, N[mdfun[x, 11.35]]}, {i, 0, im}];
mdfunh = Interpolation[mddta1d, InterpolationOrder -> 7, Method -> "Hermite", 
  PeriodicInterpolation -> True];
hxh = Derivative[1][mdfunh];
mdfunhhxxx = Derivative[3][mdfunh];
```

`im` and the `Interpolation` options are chosen to match those in `mdfun`.  Increasing `im` or the `InterpolationOrder` actually make things worse, and using `"Spline"` instead of "Hermite" has little effect on the third derivative, plotted below directly from the interpolation points of `mdfunhhxxx`.

```
ListPlot[mdfunhhxxx["ValuesOnGrid"], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Third derivative interpolation plot]

A blowup of this curve would show oscillation among adjacent points of about 0.013 for the first and last 70 points.  The central section is extremely noisy.  Smoothing of the two wings of the plot is achieved by

```
hxxxtab = LowpassFilter[mdfunhhxxx["ValuesOnGrid"], 2]; 
hxxxtab[[1]] = 0; hxxxtab[[2]] = 0; hxxxtab[[im + 1]] = 0; 
hxxxtab1d = Table[x = i N[2*Sqrt[2] π]/im; {x, hxxxtab[[i + 1]]}, {i, 0, im}];
hxxxh = Interpolation[hxxxtab1d, InterpolationOrder -> 7, Method -> "Hermite",
  PeriodicInterpolation -> True];
```

Note that this process changes somewhat the values of the third derivative for the central 6o or so points but does not convert them into a smooth curve.  Inserting `mdfunh`, `hxh`, and `hxxxh` into the equations given in the Question (and setting `Contours -> 40`) yields the desired result.

[image: Smoothed contour plot]

One should, of course, be cautious in interpreting the central portion of the curve, in light of the very noisy `hxxx` values there.

Comment: @ bbgodfrdey, Just as you illustrated, I agree with you. But problem is how can we smooth the fine structure before using `ContourPolt`.

Comment: I presume that you wish to keep the overall shape but eliminate the fast oscillations shown in the plot above.  If so, I believe that I can find a way today.  Please confirm.

Comment: @ bbgodfrey, it looks like a nice trick! I think I need some time to understand your method. Thank you very much!